# How to develop the function and simplify it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that the transfer function of a second-order low-pass filter has the form
$$T(s)=\frac{K}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{0}}\right)^{2}+2\zeta\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{0}}\right)+1}$$

The gain response is found by substituting j\omega for s to obtain

$$|T(j\omega)|=\frac{|K|}{\sqrt{\left[1-\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{0}}\right)^{2}\right]^{2}+4\zeta^{2}\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_{0}}\right)^{2}}}$$

I see absolute value and a square root, but I don't know if this is a simplified version or the substitution or not.

Then, what it is done to get the final form after the substitution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, notice that $\text{j}^2=i^2=-1$.

Well, notice that you've:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{k}}{\left(\frac{\text{s}}{\omega_0}\right)^2+2\zeta\cdot\frac{\text{s}}{\omega_0}+1}\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{k}}{\left(\frac{\text{j}\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2+2\zeta\cdot\frac{\text{j}\omega}{\omega_0}+1}=\frac{\text{k}}{\frac{\text{j}^2\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}+2\zeta\cdot\frac{\text{j}\omega}{\omega_0}+1}=\frac{\text{k}}{1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}+2\zeta\cdot\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\cdot\text{j}}\tag2$$

So, we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\text{k}}{1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}+2\zeta\cdot\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\cdot\text{j}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\left|\text{k}\right|}{\left|1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}+2\zeta\cdot\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\cdot\text{j}\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\left|\text{k}\right|}{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}\right)^2+\left(2\zeta\cdot\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\left|\text{k}\right|}{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}\right)^2+2^2\zeta^2\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\left|\text{k}\right|}{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}\right)^2+4\zeta^2\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\left|\text{k}\right|}{\sqrt{\left(1-\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2\right)^2+4\zeta^2\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I tend to make this inconvenient takes.